# How to remove a particular subdocument from all documents in collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection studentTbl with multiple documents like

```
       {
        name: "abc"
        .. 
         allotments
         [
            {
              startdate: ...
              enddate: ...
            },
            {
              startdate: ...
              enddate: ...
            }
         ]
       }

        {
        name: "def"
        .. 
         allotments
         [
            {
              startdate: ...
              enddate: ...
            },
            {
              startdate: ...
              enddate: ...
            }
         ]
       }
```

Now I want to remove all the sub document allotments from all the documents from the studentTbl collection.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all entries from the array you can do this:

```
db.studentTbl.updateMany({}, { $pull: { "allotments": { $exists: true } } })
```

or better:

```
db.studentTbl.updateMany({}, { $set: { "allotments": [] })
```

If you want to remove the entire field you can run this:

```
db.studentTbl.updateMany({}, { $unset: { "allotments": "" } })
```